# How to get parent_id using mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7

If my SQL query is like this :

```
SELECT * FROM master_lookups WHERE `type` = 'fungsi'`,
```

then the result is like this:

[image]

(image 1)

If my SQL query is like this :

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS id,
       NULL AS parent_id,
       kdsfungsi AS `code`,
       nmsfungsi AS `name`,
       'sub_fungsi' AS `type`, 
       CONCAT('{"kdfungsi":"', kdfungsi, '"}') AS information 
FROM   dblaplakgar.t_sfungsi 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 735) r
```

then the result is like this:

[image]

(image 2)

I want the result of image 2, there exists the value *parent_id*. The value of field *parent_id* is taken from the *id* in the image 1, based on the field *kdfungsi*.

So as regards the value *parent_id* in image 2, the result is like this:

- id 736, its parent id: 735
- id 737, its parent id: 735
- id 738, its parent id: 734

Once I get *parent_id*, I use this query to insert:

```
INSERT INTO master_lookups (id,parent_id,`code`,`name`,`type`,information)
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS id,
       NULL AS parent_id,
       kdsfungsi AS `code`,
       nmsfungsi AS `name`,
       'sub_fungsi' AS `type`, 
       CONCAT('{"kdfungsi":"', kdfungsi, '"}') AS information
FROM   dblaplakgar.t_sfungsi 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 735) r
```

There are *parent_id* values that are still NULL.

I need to fill the *parent_id* on image 2 based on the field *kdfungsi* as seen on image 1.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please add images to the question instead of on some pornbanner loaded host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the *id* value from the *master_lookups* table, you could do this:

```
SELECT     @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS id,
           m.id AS parent_id,
           t.kdsfungsi AS `code`,
           t.nmsfungsi AS `name`,
           'sub_fungsi' AS `type`, 
           CONCAT('{"kdfungsi":"', t.kdfungsi, '"}') AS information 
FROM       dblaplakgar.t_sfungsi t 
LEFT JOIN  master_lookups m
       ON  m.type = 'fungsi'
       AND m.code = t.kdfungsi
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 735) r
```